# How do I split a full name field (Report Builder)

Tags: reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I have a name field that displays as "Mr A Test" for every record (eg. Title initial Surname)

I need to split the full name into 3 Individual fields, Title, Initial and surname.

Is anyone able to offer any assistance? I'm fairly new to Report Builder so I have already exhausted my skill base and my searches here have so far been unsuccessful.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Can you not arrange your query to provide individual fields? This would be best.

If not, one way might be to use the split function in the expression builder eg

```
=Split(Fields!Fullname.Value, " ")
```

This results in an array of strings separated by the space. You can then access each element thus

```
=Split(Fields!Fullname.Value, " ").GetValue(x)
```

where x is a zero based index

Comment: That's great Freddie, glad you got it sorted. Btw don't forget to mark the question answered; it helps other users find it in the future